# How to completely remove Kubernetes after disabling it from Docker Desktop?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, docker-desktop

I can still access kubectl after disabling Kubernetes from Docker Desktop v4.18.0

[image: Disabled Kubernetes service in Docker Desktop]

On running the `kubectl version` command, following output is displayed:

[image: kubectl version command in terminal]

```
Environment details: 
     - OS: MacOS Ventura 13.3.1 (M1)
     - Docker Desktop: v4.18.0
```

I want to entirely remove kubectl and related services, so that I can do a fresh install of minikube for local development. Please suggest required steps for the same.

Comment: It should be the same `kubectl` (and it will never write out a PNG file; [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551))  You can `brew install minikube` alongside that `kubectl` binary and it will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per official [doc](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/kubernetes/#disable-kubernetes):

> After disabling Kubernetes Select Apply & Restart to save the
> settings.This stops and removes Kubernetes containers, and also
> removes the /usr/local/bin/kubectl command.

Below troubleshooting steps can help you:

- If you don't have kubectl installed in `/usr/local/bin`, Docker will
  install it for you on startup, so check where the kubectl is located then remove the kubectl binary.
- Check if kubernetes is still in the
  starting state.
- Check if any existing repositories are there using
  `brew search kubectl`.
- Try clean / purge data or reset to factory
  defaults in the [troubleshooting menu](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/troubleshoot/overview/#troubleshoot-menu).

Also as @David Maze suggested you can install minikube using `brew install minikube` without removing kubectl.